# How can I deploy a Flask application on Koding.com

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a Flask app, and want to deploy it on Koding so that my other team members can also view/edit it. I cloned the git repository inside a VM ( on Koding.com ), install PIP, installed dependencies, but when I start the flask server, it displays that the server has started and is running on 127.0.0.1:5000.

But when I go to :5000, it says VM is not active.

NOTE :  normally works and displays the files under VM's "Web" folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 0.0.0.0 as source IP. Also remember that, your VM will be turned off 15 minutes after logout.